# How expensive is []byte(string)?

Tags: performance, go, type-conversion

Let's convert `string` to `[]byte`:

```
func toBytes(s string) []byte {
  return []byte(s) // What happens here?
}
```

How expensive is this cast operation? Is copying performed? As far as I see in Go specification: *Strings behave like slices of bytes but are immutable*, this should involve at least copying to be sure subsequent slice operations will not modify our string `s`. What happens with reverse conversation? Does `[]byte <-> string` conversation involve encoding/decoding, like utf8 <-> runes?

Comment: I've written a benchmark [here](https://github.com/ammario/go-string-cast-benchmark) that outlines the performance impacts.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The `[]byte(s)` is not a cast but a [conversion](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions). Some conversions are the same as a cast, like `uint(myIntvar)`, which just reinterprets the bits *in place*. Unfortunately that's not the case of string to byte slice conversion. Byte slices are mutable, strings (string values to be precise) are not. The outcome is a necessary copy (mem alloc + content transfer) of the string being made. So yes, it can be costly in some scenarios.

EDIT: No encoding transformation is performed. The string (source) bytes are copied to the slice (destination) bytes as they are.

Comment: It's not very clear how `string` internally stored, as utf8 or as runes? Can you tell about this?

Comment: From http://golang.org/ref/spec#String_types: "The elements of strings have type byte and may be accessed using the usual indexing operations.". So no UTF-8, no runes. String is a numbered sequence of bytes, _any_ bytes. OTOH, many stdlib functions work only with UTF-8 encoded strings.

Comment: @demi The representation of the string is a sort of byte array. However, strings are clearly intended to contain utf-8 encoding: the `range` statement applied on strings decodes utf-8 and returns code points. [See here in the spec](http://golang.org/ref/spec#For_statements).

Comment: @jnml I expressed myself poorly. I didn't mean that a string must contain utf-8 encoded code points but that this is implicitly encouraged as there is native support for it.

Comment: The book *"Programming in Go"* made the claim: *"The `[]byte(string)` conversion is very fast (O(1)) since under the hood the `[]byte` can simply refer to the string’s underlying bytes with no copying required. The same is true of the reverse conversion, `string([]byte);` again the underlying bytes are not copied, so the conversion is O(1)."* So it seems this claim was incorrect.

Comment: FWIW, there's an [open issue](http://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=2205) requesting a feature where if the resulting byte array is never modified after a `[]byte(s)` conversion, it would use the underlying array provided by the string instead of doing a copy. Seems like a useful optimization on the surface.

Answer (score 13):

The conversion copies the bytes, but it also allocates space for the []byte on the heap.  In cases where you convert strings to []byte repeatedly, you might save memory management time by reusing the []byte and using the copy command.  (See http://golang.org/ref/spec#Appending_and_copying_slices and the special case about using a string as the source.)

In both cases of the conversion and the copy command, the copy itself is a straight byte copy which should run very quickly.  I would expect the compiler to generate some kind of repeat move instruction that the CPU executes efficiently.

The reverse conversion, making a string out of a byte slice, definitely involves allocating the string on the heap.  The immutability property forces this.  Sometimes you can optimize by doing as much work as possible with []byte and then creating a string at the end.  The bytes.Buffer type is often useful.

Chasing the red herring now, encoding and UTF-8 are not issues.  Strings and []byte can both hold arbitrary data.  The copy does not look at the data, it just copies it.  Choose words carefully when saying things like strings are *intended* to contain UTF-8 or that this is *encouraged*.  It is more accurate to simply note that some language features, such as the range clause of a for statement, *interpret* strings as UTF-8.  Just learn what interprets strings as UTF-8 and what doesn't.  Have non-UTF-8 in a string and need to range over it byte-wise?  No problem, just don't use the range clause.

```
s := "string"
for i := 0; i < len(s); i++ {
    b := s[i]
    // work with b
}
```

This is idiomatic Go.  It is not discouraged and it violates no intention.  It simply iterates over the string byte-wise, which is sometimes just what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

In complement to the answers above, in the latest [go language specification](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Conversions), the special rule of type conversion between `string` and numeric types is declared as follows:

> Specific rules apply to (non-constant) conversions between numeric types or to and from a string type. These conversions may change the representation of x and incur a run-time cost. All other conversions only change the type but not the representation of x.