Does FindStringSubmatch allocate memory?
Is the memory of the string passed to regexp.FindStringSubmatch shared with the strings in the returned slice?

Does it allocate memory? -- yes, it must allocate the slice headers. Does the original string share memory with the returned slices of the string? It's not defined, but it's generally safe to assume the language is implemented in a logical and efficient manner unless proven otherwise, See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52395730/does-slice-of-string-perform-copy-of-underlying-data/52396083#52396083

In the src/regexp/regexp.go line 1044~1057, the function make a slice and its elements are slices of original string. While slice in go is just a reference to a range of data, so the rets actually share memory with the original s.
func (re *Regexp) FindStringSubmatch(s string) []string {
    var dstCap [4]int
    a := re.doExecute(nil, nil, s, 0, re.prog.NumCap, dstCap[:0])
    if a == nil {
        return nil
    }
    ret := make([]string, 1+re.numSubexp)
    for i := range ret {
        if 2*i < len(a) && a[2*i] >= 0 {
            ret[i] = s[a[2*i]:a[2*i+1]]
        }
    }
    return ret
}

However, string is immutable in golang so the function won't cause problems.
