# Access HTTP response as string in Go

Tags: networking, go

I'd like to parse the response of a web request, but I'm getting trouble accessing it as string.

```
func main() {
    resp, err := http.Get("http://google.hu/")
    if err != nil {
        // handle error
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)

    ioutil.WriteFile("dump", body, 0600)

    for i:= 0; i < len(body); i++ {
        fmt.Println( body[i] ) // This logs uint8 and prints numbers
    }

    fmt.Println( reflect.TypeOf(body) )
    fmt.Println("done")
}
```

How can I access the response as string? `ioutil.WriteFile` writes correctly the response to a file.

I've already checked the package reference but it's not really helpful.

Answer (score 381, accepted):

`bs := string(body)` should be enough to give you a string.

From there, you can use it as a regular string.

A bit as [in this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/Zdo8YVYz08k)
(updated after [Go 1.16 -- Q1 2021 -- `ioutil` deprecation](https://golang.org/doc/go1.16#ioutil): [`ioutil.ReadAll()`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#ReadAll) => [`io.ReadAll()`](https://pkg.go.dev/io#ReadAll)):

```
var client http.Client
resp, err := client.Get(url)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer resp.Body.Close()

if resp.StatusCode == http.StatusOK {
    bodyBytes, err := io.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    bodyString := string(bodyBytes)
    log.Info(bodyString)
}
```

See also [GoByExample](http://dlintw.github.io/gobyexample/public/http-client.html).

As commented below (and in [zzn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3435777/zzn)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38674536/6309)), this is a **[conversion](https://blog.golang.org/slices#TOC_12)** (see [spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions)).
See "[How expensive is `[]byte(string)`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14373714/6309)" (reverse problem, but the same conclusion apply) where [zzzz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1065241/zzzz) mentioned:

> Some conversions are the same as a cast, like `uint(myIntvar)`, which just reinterprets the bits in place.

[Sonia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/620399/sonia) adds:

> Making a string out of a byte slice, definitely involves allocating the string on the heap. The immutability property forces this.
> Sometimes you can optimize by doing as much work as possible with []byte and then creating a string at the end. The [`bytes.Buffer`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer) type is often useful.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any suggestion how could I have figured it out on my own? How does string() do that? Why can't I see it with reflect.TypeOf?

Comment: @TiborSzasz It is a simple conversion: see https://blog.golang.org/slices#TOC_12.

Comment: A small improvement to your code would be to use `http.StatusOK` instead of the raw `200` value!

Comment: I've been doing this and finding that my request bodies always have a newline char at the end. Is this normal for a request body or is that cauased by `ioutil.ReadAll()`??

Answer (score 53):

The method you're using to read the http body response returns a byte slice:

```
func ReadAll(r io.Reader) ([]byte, error)
```

[official documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#ReadAll)

You can convert `[]byte` to a string by using

```
body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
bodyString := string(body)
```

Answer (score 17):

## Go 1.16+ update (February 2021)

Deprecation of `io/ioutil`

## code should be

```golang
var client http.Client
resp, err := client.Get(url)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer resp.Body.Close()

if resp.StatusCode == http.StatusOK {
    bodyBytes, err := io.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    // if u want to read the body many time
    // u need to restore 
    // reader := io.NopCloser(bytes.NewReader(bodyBytes))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    bodyString := string(bodyBytes)
    log.Info(bodyString)
}
```

## reference

1. https://golang.org/doc/go1.16#ioutil
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52076748/2876087

Comment: Good point. I have updated [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38673698/6309) accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

string(byteslice) will convert byte slice to string, just know that it's not only simply type conversion, but also memory copy.