# Reading on golang from http responce body

Tags: http, go

I send request to server and get answer from one. You can see my code:

```
// Some code
queryUrl, err := url.Parse(someValidStringUrl)
resp, err := client.Get(queryUrl.String())
```

Let's check `err`:

```
if err != nil {
    log.Panic("Responce:", resp, "\nError:", err)
}
```

After this I want get body of my response. I make it such way but I get empty byte slice:

```
var bytes []byte
n, err := resp.Body.Read(bytes)
if err != nil {
    log.Panic(err)
}
log.Println(n, string(bytes))
```

Example of output:

> 2017/07/13 16:32:36 0

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38673673/access-http-response-as-string-in-go) I found another way:

```
// Some code
queryUrl, err := url.Parse(someValidStringUrl)
resp, err := client.Get(queryUrl.String())
if err != nil {
    log.Panic("Responce:", resp, "\nError:", err)
}
defer resp.Body.Close()

if resp.StatusCode == 200 { // OK
    bodyBytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }
    log.Println(string(bodyBytes))
}
```

Example of output:

```html
<html lang='en'>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<title>Hello world</title>
</body>
</html>
```

Please, help me. What differences between such examples? Why do my way not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Golang's [Reader documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader)

> Read reads up to len(p) bytes into p. It returns the number of bytes read (0 <= n <= len(p)) and any error encountered. Even if Read returns n < len(p), it may use all of p as scratch space during the call. If some data is available but not len(p) bytes, Read conventionally returns what is available instead of waiting for more.
>
> When Read encounters an error or end-of-file condition after successfully reading n > 0 bytes, it returns the number of bytes read. It may return the (non-nil) error from the same call or return the error (and n == 0) from a subsequent call. An instance of this general case is that a Reader returning a non-zero number of bytes at the end of the input stream may return either err == EOF or err == nil. The next Read should return 0, EOF.

```
//Reader interface from package documentation showing 'p' is the input byte slice.
type Reader interface {
    Read(p []byte) (n int, err error)
}
```

Since you are never initializing your slice, `len(bytes)` is always 0 so it only reads 0 bytes. To do it manually like you are trying to do, you would have to initialize the slice to be non-empty and then call read multiple times until it finally returns 0 and EOF while appending bytes to some buffer that you maintain. That is why [ioutil.ReadAll](http://godoc.org/io/ioutil#ReadAll) is desired, it guarantees that everything is read correctly and you don't have to worry about handling that.

Also note `defer resp.Body.Close()` in the example. It is important to always remember to close Readers and Writers after using them.

Answer (score -1):

The response body is a Reader. According to the docs:

> Read reads up to len(p) bytes into p. It returns the number of bytes
>   read (0 <= n <= len(p)) and any error encountered. Even if Read
>   returns n < len(p), it may use all of p as scratch space during the
>   call. If some data is available but not len(p) bytes, Read
>   conventionally returns what is available instead of waiting for more.

Since the length of your byte slice `var bytes []byte` is 0 when you pass it into Read, it's never going to return you any bytes.

What you could do is to initialize your []byte to being the same size as the content returned:

```
bytes := make([]byte, resp.ContentLength)
```

Or, just use ioutil.ReadAll.

Comment: There's no guarantee that `Content-Length` will be correct